# How can I get Google Chat and Gmail notifications without having Chrome open?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, gmail, notifications, google-talk

I bought an old laptop from a friend recently, and I've been trying to get it up and running with all the services that I'd like to use.  One of these is Google Chat/Gmail.  However, the laptop isn't very powerful, and I'd rather not have to keep Chrome open all the time to get chat and mail notifications.

Basically, what I want is the old Google Talk app, but Google seems to have dropped support for that, and I can't find anywhere that I can download it.  Hangouts sort of works, but the Hangouts app requires a Chrome process to be running, and it doesn't seem to give me mail notifications.

Is there a simple way for me to get Google Chat and Gmail notifications without running Chrome constantly?

My laptop's system specs are:

- Windows 7 32-bit
- AMD Turion(tm) 64 Mobile Technology MK-36, ~2.0GHz
- 2048MB RAM

Comment: Try Pidgin - https://support.google.com/a/answer/49147?hl=en

Comment: @ultrasawblade You should format that as an answer, so I can upvote and accept it.  That is exactly what I wanted, and solves all of my problems.

Comment: I just looked up pidgin - does it do Gmail notifies?  Not clear that it does on their home page and you've got me curious now. (Might be good for an old netbook of mine..)

Comment: @JoelAZ If you look at the link ultrasawblade posted, it shows exactly how to set up both Google Chat and Gmail notifications with Pidgin.

Comment: Ok, I see it now.  Easy to overlook as it's just a single checkbox and single line in the instructions.  Breezed through the first time and missed it.  Very cool.  That Pidgin's a little swiss army knife...

Answer (score 0):

Gmail Notifier (http://www.gmailnotifier.com/download/) SEEMS to do what you want. (never used, just googled)  It's an .exe and the requirements page lists only a Win xp or better, not Chrome.

That plus Hangouts might get you were you wanna be.

Comment: This doesn't really help me.  What I want is to have those two features without having to have a Chrome process running, so having this notifier and Hangouts (which uses a Chrome process) doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: Didn't realize that the desktop hangouts app used a chrome process underneath, sry.